# Manipulating data lists in Haskell with functors

Tags: haskell

I have a datatype defined as follows:

```
data AssocList k a = 
     Nil
   | Cons(k,a,AssocList k a)
   deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Now I have some code like the following:

```
doubleMap :: (k -> a -> (k',a')) -> AssocList k a -> AssocList k' a'
doubleMap f Nil = Nil
doubleMap f (Cons(k, a, t)) = Cons(k , f k a, doubleMap f t)
```

The code is expected to take in three inputs k,a and the AssocList the AssocList looks something like:

```
(Cons(1,2,Cons(3,4,Cons(....))))
```

And what is supposed to happen is that f is a higher order function that returns a tuple of (k', a') and then I would go through the whole Cons list and apply the k' to every first argument inside Cons, and apply a' to every second argument inside of Cons

So if I called the function like:

```
doubleMap (\x y -> (x,x+y)) (Cons(1,2,Cons(3,4,Nil)))
```

I expect to get:

```
Cons(1,3,Cons(3,7,Nil))
```

Now if I use the solution I implemented above:

```
doubleMap :: (k -> a -> (k',a')) -> AssocList k a -> AssocList k' a'
doubleMap f Nil = Nil
doubleMap f (Cons(k, a, t)) = Cons(k , f k a, doubleMap f t)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘a'’ with ‘(k', a')’
      Expected: AssocList k (k', a')
        Actual: AssocList k' a'
```

Can you tell me the proper way to implement this function?

Comment: You have `Cons(k , f k a, ...)`. What is the type of `k`? What is the type of `f k a`? What do you get when you `Cons` these things together?

Comment: `Cons(k , f k a, ...)` is indeed wrong: `f` provides both the new key and the new value, in their respective new types. You can't use the old key `k`. Your code could read like `Cons(newK, newA, ...) where (newK, newA) = ....`

Comment: `Cons(k, a, AssocList k a)` is also redundant. `Cons k a (AssocList k a)` would be sufficient. (Make `Cons` a product instead of simply wrapping another product.)

Comment: @chepner that gives me /Users/yunfeichen/Desktop/CMPT 383/v4/src/AssocList.hs:16:41: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: AssocList :: k -> a -> t0
   |        
16 | doubleMap f (Cons(k, a, t)) = Cons k a (AssocList k a) so i dont think its correct

Comment: No, I mean the definition itself is redundant, not that the syntax is equivalent. There's not reason for `Cons` to map a tuple to an `AssocList k a` value it it can simply map values of type `k`, `a`, and `AssocList k a` to an `AssocLIst k a` value directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you write Cons(k, f k a, doubleMap f t) remember, that f have type (k -> a -> (k', a')) and result is (k', a'), but not a'. As a result you get Cons(k', (k', a'), doubleMap f t) instead Cons(k', a', doubleMap f t).

doubleMap rewritten with this fact in mind:

```
doubleMap :: (k -> a -> (k',a')) -> AssocList k a -> AssocList k' a'
doubleMap f Nil = Nil
doubleMap f (Cons(k, a, t)) = let (k', a') = f k a in Cons (k', a', doubleMap f t)
```

P.s. Usually type defenitions write like this (without tuple inside type constructor):

```
data AssocList k a = Cons k a (AssocList k a) | Nil
```